# How to add a view controller's view behind a current view controller?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

I have a navigation controller shows in the screen ,and I want to have another view controller's view just sit behind the current navigation controller (for some use later)
How can I do that ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide it then

`yourView.hidden=YES;`

If you want to change view arrangment bring the subview you want to the front

```
[self.view bringSubViewToFront:yourView];
```

Alternatively, create it only when you need it